# Set cookie in different folders

Tags: php, cookies, directory

I'm trying to create cookie from one folder that will also work in another.
Simply doing:

```
setcookie('favorite['.$id.']',1,time()+60*24*60*60,'/');
```

But it doesn't work. Cookies are visible in the created folder but empty in other.

Also I've tried:

```
setcookie('favorite['.$id.']',1,time()+60*24*60*60,ROOT);
setcookie('favorite['.$id.']',1,time()+60*24*60*60,HTTP_ADR);
```

Where `ROOT = dirname(__FILE__)` and `HTTP_ADR` is address of my site in `http://example.com/site`

Could it be due to problem of this array `favorite['.$id.']` ?

**UPDATE:** using in this way `echo count($_COOKIE['favorite'])`

Comment: Also. Can you provide the way you checking this cookie in another folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange.
This script which in /cookie/ foolder

```
<?
setcookie('foo[lol]', 1, time()+60*24*60*60, "/");
```

sets cookie which works even in root folder.

So make shure nothing deletes your cookies in another folder.

**EDIT:** php can't read cookies which contain brackets.  But browsers can.

**EDIT2:** no, it can, but it thinks that it is array. So to read your cookie use this code:

```
var_dump($_COOKIE['favorite'][$id]);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I'm using it like array, but it still empty.

Comment: I'm creating vookie from ajax request, could it be a reason?

Comment: My code start to work with '/' in last parameter:) You bring luck:)
Marking as right answer!

Comment: I guess it was browser problem or php bug.

Answer (score 2):

In case its not working you can store that cookie in the session and can use that cookie

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    if(isset($_COOKIE['cookiename']))
    {
        $_SESSION['cookie_name']= $_COOKIE['cookiename'];
    }
    echo $_SESSION['cookie_name'];
    ?>
```